# cakephp can not able to login with username and password

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.6.1
I'm tring to login but it says You are not authorized to access that location.
In UsersController `$this->request->is('post')` returning `false`.

AppConroller.php

```
    var $scaffold;
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
```

UsersController :

```
public $components = array('Paginator');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
    public   function login() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
        }
    }
```

User.php :

```
public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
        $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
    } else {
        $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
    }
    if (!$groupId) {
        return null;
    }
    return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
}

/*
 *  bindNode() and $actAs changes will tell ACL to skip checking User Aro’s and to check only Group Aro’s.
 *
 */

public function bindNode($user) {
    return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
}

public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester', 'enabled' => false));
```

Login.ctp :

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe inside Usercontroller change your beforefilter like this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->Auth->allow('login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add function that you want to allow into the $this->Auth->allow() parameter in beforeFilter callback function.

Example code:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->Auth->allow('login'); //function that you want to allow before authentication
}
```

Hope this help.